# how to add listview in xml file included in options menu item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to add an list of news in my application. I could successfully create this as a separate page/activity. Now I want to display the listview in the news menu item which is one of my options menu. Also I want to display each listview content as a separate activity onclick of that particuler listitem:

By this MainActivity.java my options menu is not displayed. Where is the problem?

Here is my main activity.java

```
package com.example.newlistview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.news, R.id.label, adobe_products));
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          switch( position ) {
             case 0:  Intent e = new Intent(view.getContext(), News1.class);     
                      startActivity(e);
                      break;
             case 1:  Intent f = new Intent(view.getContext(), About.class);     
                      startActivity(f);
                      break;
}

}
});

}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.news:
Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News.class);
startActivity(a);
return true;

case R.id.about:
Intent f = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
startActivity(f);
return true;

default:

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create any option menu? You probably need to create a layout for the option menu and inflate it.

For example:

/res/menu/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/news" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about" />
</menu>
```

And add following code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There should be three dots in the upper right corner of the activity. Or the hard button for the option menu of your device should be enabled.